# NullPointException on startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

So I am using the Google Drive [QuickStart](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android) tutorial to help me understand the basics of interacting with Google Drive and the code works fine on a Samsung Ace 2 running Android 2.3.6 so I am able to 
upload files to my Google Drive space.
My issue is when I run the same application on my Samsung SII running Android 4.2.2 it finds the account  and allows me to create a new file for uploading but crashes on:

```
startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
```

LogCat gives me the following :

```
03-26 18:29:39.686: E/AndroidRuntime(6775): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-256
03-26 18:29:39.686: E/AndroidRuntime(6775): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-26 18:29:39.686: E/AndroidRuntime(6775):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
03-26 18:29:39.686: E/AndroidRuntime(6775):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
03-26 18:29:39.686: E/AndroidRuntime(6775):     at com.blitz_labs.Google$3.run(Google.java:209)
03-26 18:29:39.686: E/AndroidRuntime(6775):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Relevant Code

```
public void saveFileToDrive(final String fileName) {
Thread folder = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
      public void run() {
        try {

            Files.List request = service.files().list().setQ("mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false");

          final FileList files = request.execute();     
            request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
            if (!files.getItems().isEmpty()){
                for(int i=0; i < files.getItems().size(); i++){
                    if(files.getItems().get(i).getTitle().equals("APP FOLDER")){
                        parentKind = files.getItems().get(i).getKind();
                        parentID = files.getItems().get(i).getId();
                    } 
                } 
           }else{  


                 File body = new File();
                 body.setTitle("APP FOLDER");
                 body.setDescription("App folder");
                 body.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");
                // service is an authorized Drive API service instance
                File file = service.files().insert(body).execute();
                parentKind = file.getKind();
                parentID = file.getId();
                driveFile = file;

                        Log.v("file EXISTS HERE:",""+driveFile.getTitle());

            }

            String mediaStorageDir = "/sdcard/APP FOLDER/";
            fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new java.io.File(mediaStorageDir +java.io.File.separator + fileName));
          // File's binary content
          java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(fileUri.getPath());
          FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/plain", fileContent);

          // File's metadata.
          File body = new File();  
          body.setTitle(fileContent.getName());
          body.setMimeType("text/plain");
          body.setParents(Arrays.asList(new ParentReference().setId(parentID) ));

          final File file1 = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
          if (file1 != null) {   


               runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      @Override
                      public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "file uploaded: " + file.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.v("SUCESSFULL UPLOADTO GOOGLEDRIVE",""+file1.getTitle());
                      }
                    });             
          }             

        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
            startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

      }
});
folder.start();

  }
```

Does anyone have any ideas to what maybe causing this?

I have included the file upload function where the error gets generated.

Thank you in advance, for your help.

Comment: `e` is likely `null`, can you post the rest of the code?

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I have exactly the same crash on Galaxy Nexus 4.2.2. I think maybe it's a bug.

Comment: Yes, please see my answer. May I ask are you attempting to call a function from your google oauth class in another class?. if you are then your function is not calling anything else in your google oauth class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after debugging my code I identified that the reason my application was crashing was because of I was trying to upload the file through the upload method from another class which which was alright for me because I ran the original version of the script and that authorized the application therefore allowing me to upload files to Google but not anyone else.
My solution was in my second class going back to my Google 0Aauth

```
        Intent data = new Intent();
        data.putExtra("file", filename);

    if (getParent() == null) {
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
    } else {
   getParent().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
    }
    finish();
```

Also remember to get the Extra parameters on the Google Oauth page

Answer (score 1):

You do stuff like

```
  final FileList files = request.execute();     
        request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
```

Where you'd get a NPE on the second line if you don't get files as a result.

You should protect yourself against that event with code like this

```
final FileList files = request.execute();     
if (files!=null){
        request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
}
```

Specifically, for your error you need to protect` your code like this

```
if ((e!=null) && (e.getIntent()!=null)) {
   startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
}else if (e!=null){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I've tried your solution but unfortunatly I still get the NullPointException on startActivityForResult

Comment: Well, it was more of a generic comment. Look at my modified answer.

Comment: You'd best add your own answer to the question, then, and mark it.

Comment: Hi Apologies to anyone that I may have confused the answer i previously posted stating that my issue had been resolved. I was incorrect after extensive testing with different test devices and emulators I have identified that the issue persists but I am unclear to why it is happening the error I get is always the `startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);`

When testing on my own two personal devices which both share the same google account, they work but when i send the application to other test devices it crashes on the `StartActivityForResult();`

Comment: Did you try the part that starts with `if ((e!=null) && (e.getIntent()!=null)) {` ?

Comment: yes I did, unfortunately it still crashed, but on two test devices  Ace 2 and S2 it works fine I'm able to upload and download files from my Google Drive but on all other devices it still crashes

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and i discovered that crash is inside of getIntent itself. It worked fine before on samsung note 2 but now it fails. And i don't know why. Eclipse debugger shows that some local variable o inside getIntent is null and than it crashes with NPE.

Comment: I resolved the issue. The trick was that i was passing Activity to GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2 but it needs Context. As soon as i passed Context everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Change the "this" argument to "this.getApplicatinContext()" in the first argument of GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2 method.

The solution was posted here:
[Drive SDK for Android AuthIntent is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431727/drive-sdk-for-android-authintent-is-null)