# Drive SDK for Android AuthIntent is null

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm trying to integrate Google Drive into my Android app so that I can store files in a user's Drive. I've enabled both Drive SDK and Drive API in the App Console and set up my Oauth 2 ClientIDs with my SHA1 fingerprint. As far as I can tell, everything looks good on Google's end.

Here's the code that initializes my Drive object.

```
private boolean initializeService(String accountName) {
    if(service != null) { 
        return true;
    }
    GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(mContext, DriveScopes.DRIVE); 
    mAuthIntent = null;

    if(accountName != null) {
        try {
            credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName); 
            Log.d("DriveHelper", credential.getToken());
            service = getDriveService(credential);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            if(ex instanceof UserRecoverableAuthException) {
                UserRecoverableAuthException authException = (UserRecoverableAuthException)ex;
                mAuthIntent = authException.getIntent();
                mErrorCode = CloudHelper.CONNECTION_AUTHENTICATE;
                ((Activity)mContext).startActivityForResult(mAuthIntent, REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
            } else {
                Log.e("DriveCloudHelper", "Error retrieving auth token", ex);
            }

            return false;
        } 
        getAppFolder();

        return mFileLocation != null;
    } 

    Activity activity = (Activity)mContext;
    activity.startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
    return false;
}

private Drive getDriveService(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
    return new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), credential)
    .setApplicationName("Drive Helper")
    .build();
}
```

These methods are called on a background thread and work just fine, the Account Picker appears, the Authorization window appears, all good. My `getAppFolder` method looks for a specific folder and creates it if not present without any issue (on the same background thread).

However, when I go to upload a file to Drive, the first operation I try on a new background thread causes a `UserRecoverableAuthException`, but a new exception occurs when I call `getIntent` because there's no Intent provided, and the detail message is `AppDownloadRequired`.

Here's the method that's generating the exception.

```
private String getIdFromFolder(String location, String name, boolean create) {
    try {
        String maskedName = name.replaceAll("/", "");
        String query = "title contains '" + maskedName + "' and '" + location + "' in parents";
        FileList list = service.files().list().setMaxResults(1).setQ(query).execute();
        List<File> files = list.getItems();

        if (files.isEmpty()) {
            return create ? createSubFolder(location, name) : null;
        }

        return files.get(0).getId();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Eat the exception here
        Log.w("DriveCloudHelper", e);
    }
    return create ? createSubFolder(location, name) : null;
}
```

And here's the stacktrace:

```
 com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:222)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:836)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:412)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:345)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:463)
    at net.wishfullthinking.groceryhelper.interfaces.DriveCloudHelper.getIdFromFolder(DriveCloudHelper.java:269)
    at net.wishfullthinking.groceryhelper.interfaces.DriveCloudHelper.uploadDatabaseToCloud(DriveCloudHelper.java:405)
    at net.wishfullthinking.groceryhelper.interfaces.DriveCloudHelper.synchFileToCloud(DriveCloudHelper.java:368)
    at net.wishfullthinking.groceryhelper.interfaces.CloudHelper.mergeCloudStoreCollection(CloudHelper.java:472)
    at net.wishfullthinking.groceryhelper.interfaces.CloudHelper.access$10(CloudHelper.java:454)
    at net.wishfullthinking.groceryhelper.interfaces.CloudHelper$4.run(CloudHelper.java:444)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 Caused by: com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException: AppDownloadRequired
    at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.getToken(GoogleAccountCredential.java:192)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:217)
    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `mContext.getApplicationContext()` in your `GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2` call rather than `mContext` as that seems to have fixed [similar issues](https://github.com/googledrive/appdatapreferences-android/issues/2) elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you! That's been plaguing me for days now!