# Save and restore token for Google Drive android

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I tried [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android) example from google to authenticate with Google Drive and it can work. But the problem is that I don't know how to restore the previous success login from users. 
For example, when users login success, the next time they go to my app, they don't need to login again. I look in the `GoogleAccountCredential` class, it only have `getToken` method and don't have 'setToken` so I don't know how to do. And the document doesn't say anything about it. 
Here is my try:

```
   credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(context, DriveScopes.DRIVE);

   // try to add login account into credential
   String accountName = SharePreferenceHelper.getDriveAccount(context);
    if (accountName != null) {
    credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
    service = getDriveService(credential);
    }

     // try to get token again
   try {
    String token = credential.getToken();   
        Log.d(TAG,"token = " + token);
    } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException ex) {
                 startActivityForResult(ex.getIntent(), requestCode);

    }
```

Does anybody know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not do this manually. It is already taken care of by `GoogleAccountCredential`

This call

`credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, scopes);`

will automatically restore the saved token if its previously saved.

You can check out a sample source code of my app here:
https://github.com/madhur/GAnalytics/blob/develop/src/in/co/madhur/ganalyticsdashclock/MainActivity.java

the difference it uses Google Analytics instead of Google Drive.

Comment: Thanks, actually I did it but it doesn't work. And I found that my problem is initialize the GoogleAccountCredential with wrong context (I put it into service), so I must use getApplicationContext() to initialize the credential, like this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431727/drive-sdk-for-android-authintent-is-null